# I get a "Bean identifier index inconsistency detected" exception with Wildfly 10.1.0

Tags: wildfly, infinispan

I just deployed my application on Wildfly 10.1.0 and everything is working fine and the session is replicating across the two servers. When I shut down one of the servers, the application stops working and in the logs I find the following exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000227: Bean identifier index inconsistency detected - the distributed container probably does not work with identical applications
Expected hash: -2060331753
Current index: BeanIdentifierIndex [hash=-1812185259, indexed=31] 
     0: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_EAI.war%HttpSession
     1: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_ESB.war%HttpSession
     2: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_ESB.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar%HttpSession
     3: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_ESB.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar%HttpSession
     4: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/ajaxanywhere-1.2.1.jar%HttpSession
     5: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/axis-1.4.jar%HttpSession
     6: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar%HttpSession
     7: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/ckeditor-java-core-3.5.3.jar%HttpSession
     8: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/dwr-2.0.2.jar%HttpSession
     9: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.0.6.jar%HttpSession
    10: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/openamf-1.12.jar%HttpSession
    11: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/sis-utility-0.5.jar%HttpSession
    12: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/standard-1.0.6.jar%HttpSession
    13: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.1.jar%HttpSession
    14: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.24.jar%HttpSession
    15: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-unstandard-20060829.jar%HttpSession
    16: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-jsp-3.0.1.jar%HttpSession
    17: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/content/PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/lib/velocity-tools-2.0.jar%HttpSession
    18: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%PATT_EAR.ear%HttpSession
    19: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%PATT_EAR.ear/ArchivageRemoting.war%HttpSession
    20: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_BATCH.war/WEB-INF/classes%HttpSession
    21: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_REMOTING.war%HttpSession
    22: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_SERVICES.war%HttpSession
    23: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%PATT_EAR.ear/PATT_WEB.war/WEB-INF/classes%HttpSession
    24: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%com.sun.jsf-impl:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
    25: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.hibernate.validator.cdi:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
    26: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.jberet.jberet-core:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
    27: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.jboss.as.jsf:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
    28: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.jboss.jts:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
    29: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
    30: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession

    at org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl.checkBeanIdentifierIndexConsistency(HttpSessionContextImpl.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl.associate(HttpSessionContextImpl.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl.associate(HttpSessionContextImpl.java:23)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle.requestInitialized(HttpContextLifecycle.java:237)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener.requestInitialized(WeldInitialListener.java:152)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.requestInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:246)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:291)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I handled this problem. The problem is a difference in deployment structure. May be a new module or library.

On my servers I turned on DEBUG level for `org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap` and saw

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000145: Bean identifier index built:
  BeanIdentifierIndex [hash=-1846478689, indexed=8]
0: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%/media/disk/Program_Files/wildfly-10.1.0-money-2/standalone/deployments/money-rest-v1-app.ear/money-ejb-module.jar%HttpSession
     1: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%com.sun.jsf-impl:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
     2: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%money-rest-v1-app.ear%HttpSession
     3: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%money-rest-v1-app.ear/money-rest-v1-war-module.war/WEB-INF/classes%HttpSession
     4: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.hibernate.validator.cdi:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
     5: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.jberet.jberet-core:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
     6: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.jboss.as.jsf:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
     7: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi:main.additionalClasses%HttpSession
```

One bean indentifier contains the full deployment path. On second server this path is different. So the hash is different.

I deployed project as compressed archive and problem gone.

The second approach is `-Dorg.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization=false`. This property is described in [19.1.9. Bean identifier index optimization](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/configure.html#_bean_identifier_index_optimization)